# Additional http requests from config when running karma tests in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up a Karma test suite and the baseline for my code is the [mean stack](http://mean.io). I'm trying to write some tests (specifically login), and it looks like:

```
(function() {
  describe('LoginController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('mean'));

    var scope, rootScope, LoginController, $httpBackend, $location;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_, _$location_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      rootScope = $rootScope.$new();

      LoginController = $controller('LoginController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $rootScope: rootScope
      });

      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

      $location = _$location_;
    }));

    it('should show danger when wrong credentials are used', function() {
      scope.credentials = {
        email: 'test@email.com',
        password: 'password'
      }

      $httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/v1/user/auth').respond({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Invalid User'
      });


      scope.authenticate();
      $httpBackend.flush();

      expect(scope.status_object).toEqualData({text: 'Invalid User', class: 'danger', show: true});
    });
  });
})();
```

In my `public/js/config.js`, I have some additional logic that loads some other http requests. In my `karma` console, I get:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /lang/en-US.json
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/v1/user/session
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) LoginController should show danger when wrong credentials are used FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET /lang/en-US.json
    Expected POST /api/v1/user/auth
```

How can I set up my test to not get those?

*karma.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '../../',


        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'public/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'public/lib/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
            'public/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
            'public/lib/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js',
            'public/js/**/*.js',
            'test/karma/unit/**/*.js'

        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'test/coverage/**/*.*'
        ],


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        //reporters: ['progress'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        // coverage
        preprocessors: {
            // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
            // do not include tests or libraries
            // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
            'public/js/controllers/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
            'public/js/services/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
            'public/js/config.js': ['coverage'],
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'html',
            dir: 'test/coverage/'
        },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera
        // - Safari (only Mac)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows)
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

My `public/js/config.js` has:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'UserService', 'CompanyService', function($rootScope, $location, UserService, CompanyService) {
  $rootScope.globals = {};

  $rootScope.$on('login', function(event, data) {
    $rootScope.api_key = data.api_key;
    CompanyService.get(data.user.company_id);
  });

  UserService.checkAuth().then(function(response) {
    if(response.data.user) {
      // Logged in user
      $rootScope.$broadcast('login', response.data);

      $rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation) {
        $rootScope.globals.accessPath = newLocation.split('/')[1];

        if(newLocation !== '/login') {
          if(UserService.getAccess() !== $rootScope.globals.accessPath) {
            alert('Invalid access');
            UserService.logout();
          }
        } else {
          $location.path(UserService.getAccess());
        }
      });
    } else {
      UserService.logout();
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Your controller is making a request on the en-US locale json, which is not served by Karma. That throws a 404 error and breaks your test. Could you add your Karma config please?

Comment: Ok thanks. Loading fixtures in Karma isn't a piece of cake but if you cannot mock this locale request, you could start looking at https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/858

Comment: What's in `public/js/config.js`? I don't think it should kick in automatically. Can you add a link to that file in your question?

Comment: @Sylvain added my config file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the call to *UserService.checkAuth()* to another module, e.g. 'init-module' and have the call in the run block of that module.
Then have your module depend on the init-module so Angular loads it and executes its run block:

```
angular.module('init-module', []).run(function() {
     // call UserService.checkAuth() here
})
angular.module('my-production-module', ['init-module']);
```

When unit testing, you can mock the entire init-module before the spec runs by executing:

```
angular.module('init-module', function () {});
```

From AngularJS [module documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) - 
"...break your application to multiple modules...
...And an application level module which depends on the above modules, and which has initialization code...
The reason for this breakup is that in your tests, it is often necessary to ignore the initialization code, which tends to be difficult to test. By putting it into a separate module it can be easily ignored in tests. The tests can also be more focused by only loading the modules that are relevant to tests"

Comment: Do I put `angular.module('init-module', function () {});` in every test file?

Comment: You can create a spec-helper class with a beforeEach method outside the context of a specific describe. Have your test runner load the spec-helper class and the beforeEach function written there will run before every it spec automatically